# com.google.inject.CreationException with Functional Test using Play Framework's WSTestClient

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

I'm trying to mock a webservice using [`WsTestClient`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWebServiceClients) provided by the Play Framework.

Injecting an `WsTestClient` instance into a Play test application seemed straight forward:

```
import javax.inject.Inject

import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder
import play.core.server.Server
import play.api.routing.sird._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.test._
import play.api.inject._
import play.api.libs.ws.WSClient
import scala.concurrent.Await

class Service @Inject ()(wsClient:WSClient) {
  def query = wsClient.url("/service").get()
}

class WebServiceMockingRequestSuite extends FunSuite {

  test("Webservice request") {

    Server.withRouter() {
        case GET(p"/service") => Action {
          Results.Ok(JsNumber(42))
        }
      } { implicit port =>
        WsTestClient.withClient { client =>

          val app = GuiceApplicationBuilder().bindings(bind[WSClient].to(client))
          val service = app.injector.instanceOf[Service]

          import concurrent.duration._
          val response = Await.result(service.query,3.seconds)
          assert(response.body == "42")
        }
      }
  }
}
```

But during test application startup, I ran into the following exception:

```
[info] - Mocked webservice request *** FAILED ***
[info]   com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
[info] 
[info] 1) A binding to play.api.libs.ws.WSClient was already configured at playsample.webservice.tests.WebServiceMockingRequestSuite$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(WebServiceMockingTestSuite.scala:32):
[info] Binding(interface play.api.libs.ws.WSClient to ProviderTarget(play.api.inject.BindingKey$$anon$1@5488669d)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1).
[info]   at play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSModule.bindings(AhcWS.scala:374):
[info] Binding(interface play.api.libs.ws.WSClient to ProviderConstructionTarget(class play.api.libs.ws.ahc.WSClientProvider) in interface javax.inject.Singleton) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
[info] 
[info] 1 error
[info]   at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:466)
[info]   at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:155)
[info]   at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
[info]   at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
[info]   at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)
[info]   at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:181)
[info]   at playsample.webservice.tests.WebServiceMockingRequestSuite$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(WebServiceMockingTestSuite.scala:33)
[info]   at playsample.webservice.tests.WebServiceMockingRequestSuite$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(WebServiceMockingTestSuite.scala:30)
[info]   at play.api.test.WsTestClient$class.withClient(WSTestClient.scala:79)
[info]   at play.api.test.WsTestClient$.withClient(WSTestClient.scala:87)
```

It is interesting to note that things are working fine if the `WSTestClient` instance is directly injected like this:

```
test("Webservice request without service instance") {

  Server.withRouter() {
      case GET(p"/service") => Action {
        Results.Ok(JsNumber(42))
      }
    } { implicit port =>

      WsTestClient.withClient { client =>

        val app = GuiceApplicationBuilder().bindings(bind[WSClient].to(client))

        import concurrent.duration._
        val response = Await.result(client.url("/service").get(),3.seconds)
        assert(response.body == "42")
      }
    }
}
```

This test passes as expected without throwing a `com.google.inject.CreationException` exception.

Comment: If all you need is that `client`, why create the entire application?

Comment: The idea was that the entire application (spun up with the `GuiceApplicationBuilder`) can then interact with the web-service started at a random port via `Server.withRouter()`.
I've since found [play-mockws](https://github.com/leanovate/play-mockws), which works great in mocking out external web-service responses.

Answer (score 0):

After reading up more on the [Testing with Guice](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWithGuice) page from the Play Framework documentation, I was able to fix the issue.

Following the hint given in the thrown expression above (`A binding to play.api.libs.ws.WSClient was already configured`), I replaced

```
val app = GuiceApplicationBuilder().bindings(bind[WSClient].to(client))
```

with

```
val app = GuiceApplicationBuilder().overrides(bind[WSClient].to(client))
```

to make the test work as expected.

The following test is working nicely now:

```
import javax.inject.Inject

import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder
import play.core.server.Server
import play.api.routing.sird._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.test._
import play.api.inject._
import play.api.libs.ws.WSClient
import scala.concurrent.Await

class Service @Inject ()(wsClient:WSClient) {
  def query = wsClient.url("/service").get()
}

class WebServiceMockingRequestSuite extends FunSuite {

  test("Webservice request") {

    Server.withRouter() {
        case GET(p"/service") => Action {
          Results.Ok(JsNumber(42))
        }
      } { implicit port =>
        WsTestClient.withClient { client =>

          val app = GuiceApplicationBuilder().overrides(bind[WSClient].to(client))
          val service = app.injector.instanceOf[Service]

          import concurrent.duration._
          val response = Await.result(service.query,3.seconds)
          assert(response.body == "42")
        }
      }
  }
}
```